# How Do I Remove Multiple Files Using The Terminal

Tags: command-line

I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts and i want to remove the following files using the terminal:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list.save
/home/jatin/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
/home/jatin/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb.1
/home/jatin/.cache/software-center/piston-helper/rec.ubuntu.com,api,1.0,recommend_app,google-earth-stable,,13c5f00780e1a1b88538de42b80aaada
/home/jatin/.cache/software-center/rnrclient/reviews.ubuntu.com,reviews,api,1.0,reviews,filter,en,any,any,any,google-earth-stable,page,1,helpful,,ea694de2da0c9426e7b795c702d8b1d2
/home/jatin/Desktop/Debians/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
/home/jatin/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/128x128/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/16x16/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/32x32/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/48x48/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/64x64/mimetypes/application-vnd-google-earth-kml.png
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.google-earth.kmz.xml
/var/cache/apt/archives/google-earth-stable_6.0.3.2197-r0_amd64.deb
```

and they are scattered in the computer. is there a command to remove them all at once?

Comment: You asked before how to format a block of text. Start editing, select the block of text and press the **<$>** button to format the whole block of text with one click.

Comment: Don't delete the files inside (`/usr/share`) manually .It will break your system.If you want to remove a package then run `sudo apt-get purge package` command.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use rm ?

```
sudo rm path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you found the list of files you pasted on the question somehow, you can use `rm` to delete all of them at one go using the following:

Copy the list of files to `gedit`(paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) and then replace(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) newlines(`\n`) by a space (`' '`) and then copy the text and type `rm` and paste the copied text.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your list of files it seems that you installed google-earth-stable directly from a deb package (/home/jatin/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb).

If what you want to achieve is removing the package from your computer, type `sudo dpkg -r google-earth-stable`

Comment: it says:
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching google-earth-stable

Comment: How did you install google-earth-stable? using the Software center? If so, you can easily remove it from the Software Center. For files in  /home/jatin, like suggested just use rm to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copy and pasted that list of files from somewhere. If it's the output of a command you ran in the terminal, you can pipe this output to `xargs rm`.

But before you do that, I see files in `/usr/share/` in your list, which suggest they were installed by a package, apparently `google-earth-stable`. First uninstall that:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge google-earth-stable
```

Once that's done, run your (search?) command again and pipe it to `xargs rm` like this:

```
your_search_cmd | xargs rm
```